# Almost 100% failure when 1st time running the web scraping VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I wrote this VBA to scrape table from the website and there's a weird thing every time I run this code. When I first run this VBA it definitely fails to scrape designated table form the web (there're around 1700 rows of data and the code scrapes nothing) and the second time I run it the code can scrape the table that I want. This happens every day and I'm quite confused by this issue since I didn't test the code on other's computer so I'm wondering is it just just because of my computer config or I made any mistakes during the coding?

Below is the worksheets screenshot if you're interested in testing on your own PC

[image]

```
Sub CopyFromHKEXWebsite()
    Dim ie As Object, btnmore As Object, tbl As Object
    Dim rr As Object, cc As Object, r As Integer, c As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current PI Debt List").UsedRange.Clear
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ie
       ' .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Debt-Securities?sc_lang=en"
        
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy
        
        'display 100 items******
        .document.getElementsByClassName("select_items")(0).setAttribute "style", "display: block"
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While .Busy  'wait for scriptcode to execute
        .document.getElementsByClassName("select_items")(0).Children(2).Click
        
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy
        
        'professional filter******
        .document.getElementsByName("select2")(0).Value = "Professional"
        Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While .Busy
        .document.getElementsByClassName("etps_apply_btn")(0).Click
        
            Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy  'wait for scriptcode to execute
          
        Do
            Set tbl = .document.getElementsByClassName("table_debtsecurities")(0)
            Set btnmore = .document.getElementsByClassName("loadmore")(0)
            cnt = cnt + 1
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
            
        Loop While tbl Is Nothing Or btnmore Is Nothing And cnt < 7 'maximum attempts = 6
        
        Do While btnmore.getattribute("style") = ""
            btnmore.Click
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While .Busy
        Loop
    
    End With
'get data from table
    r = tbl.Rows.Length - 1
    c = tbl.Rows(0).Cells.Length - 1
    
    ReDim arr(0 To r, 0 To c)
    
    Set rr = tbl.Rows
    For i = 0 To r
        Set cc = rr(i).Cells
        For j = 0 To c
            arr(i, j) = cc(j).innertext
        Next
    
    Next
    
    ie.Quit
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current PI Debt List").Cells(1, 1).Resize(r + 1, c + 1) = arr
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current PI Debt List")
        .UsedRange.WrapText = False
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's possible your `Do...Loop While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy` loops do not actually detect when the page is finished doing whatever it's doing (fetching additional data etc) on the first run.  On the second run the page is maybe loading data from the cache, and so everything happens to work because it's much faster to build/update the page.

Comment: What happens on the first run?  Do you get an error, and if so what is it?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't get an error during the first run. The code scrapes data and copies it to worksheet ```Current PI Debt List``` and you'll get a blank worksheet after the 1st run. The 2nd run the code will scrape the data to worksheet ``Current PI Debt List```.

Comment: Where in that code are you actually copying any data to Excel?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry for the omission, I just edited my post and add copy data to excel macro

Comment: Where does that code sit relative to the previous posted Sub?  It might be more useful to edit the original code to include it.

Comment: @TimWilliams I merged two sections into one, this is my complete code

Comment: Sorry I'm at work and that URL's not accessible to me for testing...